# ASP.net and Jquery before Page Load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am new to coding in Jquery and ASP.net. I have read many articles on how to display loading please wait before the page actually loads. I do not want it after the page loads I want it before so I thought using document ready should handle this.

This is my shot at it.

I downloaded Jquery 1.7.1.js and added it to my solution.

The below is my code.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict()(function ($) {
    alert("not loaded");
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
  alert("loaded");
 });
}); 
</script>
```

I also tried the below: how this does not display the alert messages.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/jscript">

if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
// good to go!
}


 var interval = setInterval(function() {
if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
    clearInterval(interval);
    alert("my message while loading")
}    
}, 100);
```

Comment: Well, the document isn't going to load at all until *after* the server-side code executes.  And the document *includes* the JavaScript code.  There are some options available for creating a "loading" element on a page.  Maybe initially load a minimal page with almost nothing but that, and then via AJAX load the rest of the content?

Comment: dang, that's what take longer, the server-side code. Do you possible have an example?

Comment: That's a *very broad* question.  Entirely re-structuring your page to load minimal markup and then fetch the rest of the contents via AJAX is no small task.

Answer (score 1):

**$(document).ready()**

- Ideal for one time initialization.
- Optimization black magic; may run slightly earlier than pageLoad().
- Does not re-attach functionality to elements affected by partial
  postbacks.

**pageLoad()**

- Unsuitable for one time initialization if used with UpdatePanels.
- Slightly less optimized in some browsers, but consistent.
- Perfect for re-attaching functionality to elements within
  UpdatePanels.

The window.load however will wait for the page to be fully loaded, this includes inner frames, images etc.

This might help you

```
 <div id="dvLoading"></div>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function(){
          $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
        });
    </script>
```

CSS

```
#dvLoading

    {
           background:#000 url(images/loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
           height: 100px;
           width: 100px;
           position: fixed;
           z-index: 1000;
           left: 50%;
           top: 50%;
           margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
        }
```

Try This as well,

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    alert('page loaded');  // alert to confirm the page is loaded    
    $('.divClassName').hide(); //enter the class or id of the particular html element which you wish to hide. 
});
```

Comment: it didn't do anything. Just takes it time loading.

Comment: is the best solution then to create a Page that just says loading then redirect the user once the server stuff is done?

Comment: If you want to wait until server side finished its stuff and then redirect to another page then AJAX load, Ajax Post will helpful for you.